# Varnish (3.0.3) & Facebook connect (wordpress on nginx)

Tags: facebook, wordpress, varnish

I'm having some troubles configuring the `default.vcl` of `Varnish 3.0.3` to allow log in to my website via Facebook Connect. The Facebook API is correctly configured, but it appears my site is not 'allowing' the log in, despite the visitor being returned from Facebook after 'signing in'. Registration is successful and being recorded on my database.

Can somebody please help me configure my `default.vcl`? I've spent days trying to find the information to help me on the internet, but I a) I'm not too familiar with `Varnish` and b) there's not a lot of information currently out there.

The closest I can get to a solution is: http://drupal.org/node/1196916#31

My varnish config: http://pastebin.com/LWGRey8e

Currently I'm using the `WP-FB AutoConnect` wordpress plugin and have contacted the plugin author but he has never heard of Varnish :-s

Other details:

Site URL: livefeeedietravelling (dot com)

Varnish: 3.0.3

Wordpress Version: 3.5

Server: nginx/1.2.6 (with APC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the issue by handling the cookies different in the `sub vcl_recv` section of varnish.vcl.

```
# admin users & facebook logged in users always miss the cache
if( req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_logged_in_" || req.http.Cookie ~ "fbsr_"
|| req.http.Cookie ~ "comment_author_"
){
return (pass);
}
```

the same code can be used in `sub vcl_fetch depending on how you want to handle it.

Thanks all for their help, hope this is useful to some.

Answer (score 0):

The default vcl_hash only hashes on url and host, could it be that you need to add the cookie to that? I saw you posted an outdated vcl_hash on the other thread. An up to date version for varnish 3 would look something like:

```
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    hash_data(req.http.host);
    if (req.http.Cookie) {
            hash_data(req.http.Cookie);
    }
    return (hash);
}
```

Comment: Hi Clarence, thanks for the response. I think I'm out of my depth with this varnish config. I've tried inserting the above code into my .vcl, but with no luck. On comment number #13 of http://drupal.org/node/884350 it shows the set req.http.Cookie for the facebook cookie but I've got no idea if I need to input that somewhere into my code or not? Taylor-Jasko has also been helping me out http://serverfault.com/questions/463178/varnish-3-0-3-facebook-connect-wordpress-on-nginx but I'm still unsure of exactly how to configure my .vcl file... Any further help is GREATLY appreciated, thanks, Paul